# Нет перевода "No improvement" в отклонении правок

Tags: дефект, локализация

Нет перевода причины отклонения правки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переводы были выполнены. Но еще не подхватились сайтом. Будет в ближайших сборках.